# servicestack oauth2 google authentication not working for selfhosted sites

Tags: oauth, servicestack, self-hosting

I've been trying to add the OAuth2 provider for Google to a proof of concept application built on ServiceStack however I keep getting the following error when I try to initiate a login...

```
This method requires a current HttpContext. Alternatively, use an overload of this method that allows you to pass in information without an HttpContext`enter code here`

[Auth: 11/21/2013 10:29:25 PM]: [REQUEST: {provider:googleoauth}] System.InvalidOperationException: This method requires a current HttpContext. Alternatively, use an overload of this method that allows you to pass in information without an HttpContext. at DotNetOpenAuth.Requires.ValidState(Boolean condition, String message) at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.GetRequestFromContext() at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(HttpRequestBase request) at ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Provider.Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Auth request) at ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Authenticate(Auth request, String provider, IAuthSession session, IAuthProvider oAuthConfig) at ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Post(Auth request) at ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Get(Auth request) at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object ) at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequestContext requestContext, Object instance, TRequest request)
```

I've also downloaded the demo app SocialBootstrapApi and added the Google Oauth2 provider to it and was able to get it to work.  I've copied over the config from the web.config into the app.config file of the self hosted project but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be great!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [ServiceStack.AuthWeb.Tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/tests/ServiceStack.AuthWeb.Tests) is an ASP.NET WebHost showing [all the ServiceStack AuthProviders](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.AuthWeb.Tests/AppHost.cs#L78) working within a single app.

Note the **OAuth2** providers use additional configuration specified in the [Web.config](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.AuthWeb.Tests/Web.config) which requires that you register your own application to get your Consumer Key and Secret for your app. For testing purposes you can use the ServiceStack Test keys already embedded in the Web.config.

The [OAuth2 section in the Authentication wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#oauth-configuration) provides the urls where you can register your application for each provider.

Comment: I'm marking this correct...because technically it is.  However, I'm still unable to get oauth2 to work in a self hosted app using servicestack.  It works perfectly when you use it with the web hosted apps.  If you know of any projects out there that have done this could you pass them along.  Being able to host servicestack as a stand alone app is key for my overall architecture.

Comment: @Dan Yeah I've found that DotNetOpenAuth doesn't work properly when it's hosted in a self-hosted HttpListener, so anything requiring DNOA to work, e.g. OAuth2 supported is limited to ASP.NET hosts at this time. Add a [feature request](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) if you would like to see this researched further.